# sending text to textarea using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, richtextarea

I want to send some text over to textarea using selenium in python but I cannot find any way. I have tried every name, class and id to input text but they all report back error.however i am able to access all other buttons and text box but this particular one appears to be hidden or something. this is what the relevant part of the page looks like. Thanks in advance.

```
<form id="codeForm" action="#" method="post" name="name">    
<input type="hidden" value="2|8cd2d2b2|99adc339062516b09ca981066acce4e4|1439567340" name="_xsrf"></input>     
<div class="row top-buffer"> ::before
    <div class="col-xs-12">         
        <div id="code-editor-container">           
            <textarea id="code" class="placeholder" style="width: 100%; resize: none; height: 20px; display: none;" rows="1" cols="72" placeholder="enter" name="code"></textarea>  
            <div class="CodeMirror cm-s-solarized cm-s-light CodeMirror-wrap " style="width: 100%; height: 50%;"> 
                <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 3px; height: 0px; top: 5px; left: 29px;">
                    <textarea wrap="off" style="position: absolute; padding: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1em; outline: medium none;" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0">
                    </textarea> 
                </div>"
```

Comment: What do you mean? How have you attempted to send text? All I see is HTML

Comment: I tried using "search = br.find_element_by_name('_xsrf')" and then sending keys to the variable but it didn't work out. Also note that not only I tried _xsrf but every possible name/id/class I could find on that webpage but none input the keys into text area as you may see the text area in the deep structure has no name/id to begin with.

Comment: Use this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49372336/how-can-i-add-a-text-in-textarea-by-selenium-python?noredirect=1#comment85748053_49372336