# How can I add a text in textarea form (in HTML tag) by selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textarea, sendkeys

I have this HTML code:

```
<form class="_b6i0l"><textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
<textarea aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="_bilrf" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" style="height: 18px;"></textarea>
</form>
```

I want write a text in the filed. But, this error is happened:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <textarea class="_bilrf"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

My code which sends the text is:

```
add_comment_box= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea._bilrf")))
time.sleep(5)

add_comment_box.send_keys("nice!")
```

Could you help me, please?

Comment: Do you have 2 textarea inside form?

Comment: No, there is just one.

Comment: @hamed baziyad, the HTML from your post has 2 `textarea`.

Comment: Oh dear, the firs one is start tag and the second is end tag. I thought your mean is something else.

Comment: @Ratmir Asanov Are you have any idea? It is very essential for me. Could you share my question, pleas?

Comment: @ Florent B Are you have any idea? It is very essential for me. Could you share my question, pleas?

Comment: @hamed baziyad, try with a different driver. If it works then it's an issue with the driver. If not then you are either selecting the wrong element or it's a timing issue, in which case you should use a waiter to wait for the expected state or for no exception if the state can't be obtained.

Comment: @Florent B. Thank you. But, I could solve the problem. You can help another people by voting the answer.

Comment: @hamed baziyad, by setting the value directly, you are no longer emitting the events that the page might rely on. Thus you are no longer simulating the input from a user. It might be alright if you are scraping/automating the page, but it's not if you are testing the page. Note that your post is unlikely to be useful given that we still don't know why the element is considered not interractable by Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than send_keys, we can use this section:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea._bilrf"), "nice!")
```